# highcharts- I would like to change the axis value while leaving the graph intact

Tags: highcharts, axis

[image]

I want to change the axis of the values while leaving the drawing maximum,minimum of the point and dot of values in graph.

I did the erasing of the axis of the value.

I want to add the value what I want at each end of the axis.

If you have any knowledge of it, please let me know.

I want to solve this problem. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying labels on the begging and the end of the axis use [axis.showFirstLabel/showLastLabel](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.showFirstLabel) option (set them to true). You might need to set [axis.startOnTick/endOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick) to true.

If you want to change when the labels are displayed inside the axis - you can set [axis.tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPosition).

```
  xAxis: {
    endOnTick: true,
    showFirstLabel: true,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
 //   tickPositions: [1, 3, 5]
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/uqf61ppv/

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot. :)
I was able to solve the problem.